# Change other EXE's icon programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi, executable

Is it possible to change another exe's (possibly created by VC, CPP builder etc) icon programmatically in Delphi? There are numerous applications that can do this magic - just curious to know how can we achieve this in Delphi.

Comment: You could open the exe and locate the `resource section`, then update the correct entry. Some background for the `PE` format might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx, you should also be able to use `win32` methods like `BeginUpdateResource,
UpdateResource and EndUpdateResource`

Comment: Do what Krister says. Those are the APIs. Note that you'll invalidate the digital certificate.

Comment: This is another example of a question tagged "Delphi" that has nothing in particular to do with Delphi (it's about the Win32 platform and API).

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan I was also trying to change icon of an exe file with this method here ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources ) , what do you mean by invalidate the digital certificate?

Comment: @Notidart A signed executable cannot be modified without invalidating that signature.

Comment: whoops forgot to up rep you, thanks david for that note